# Flex multiple .l file arguments don't work? (eg "flex a.l b.l")

Tags: flex-lexer

I finally have a comfortable-enough workflow for writing my `flex` programs, and I'll work `bison` into it soon (I dabbled with it before but I restarted my project entirely).

`flex yy.l; flex flip.l` will generate a `lex.yy.c` and `lex.flip.c`correctly, since I use the prefix option. But I am curious why `flex yy.l flip.l` or `flex *.l` does not.

`gcc lex*` seems to work perfectly fine when all .c files are correctly generated, as by the first command, but trying the same shortcut with flex produces a single `lex.yy.c` file, which seemed valid up until the unprocessed flip.l file pasted on the end, preventing gcc compilation.

Is this just flex telling me my workflow is dumb and I should use more start conditions in a big file? I'd prefer not to, at least until I have a more complete program to tweak for speed.

My workflow is:

```
fg 1; fg 2; fg 3; fg 4; flex a.l; flex flip.l; flex rot.l; gcc -g lex*; ./a.out < in
```

With `nano` editors as jobs 1, 2, 3, 4 to `fg` out of the background.

I'm lexing the file in this order: `flip`, `rot`, `a`, `rot`, `flip`. And it works, and I can even use preprocessor definitions `gcc -DALONE` to correctly compile my .c files alone, for testing.

Comment: The *flex(1)* command only takes one file argument. You would normally only have one scanner in a program.

Comment: Okay. Is there a meaning to that (1)?

Comment: Some lexer generators such as [RE/flex](https://github.com/Genivia/RE-flex) support an "import" command to modularize lexer specifications into multiple `.l` files. This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but at least it can make a larger project more manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what flex is telling you, if anything, is to learn how to use `make` rather than trying to put together massive build commands.

It's true that flex will only process one file per invocation. On the other hand, both gcc and clang are simply drivers which invoke the actual compiler(s) and linker(s) so that you don't have to write more complicated build recipes. You could easily write a little driver program which invoked flex multiple times, once per argument, but it would be even simpler to use `make`, with the additional advantage that flex would only be invoked as necessary.

In fact, most large C projects do not use gcc's ability to compile multiple files in a single invocation. Instead, they let `make` figure out which object files need to be rebuilt (because the corresponding source file changed), thereby considerably speeding up the debug/edit/build cycle.